# Cmake: command not found on macOS while I installed cmake-gui

Tags: macos, cmake, terminal, zsh, cmake-gui

I've installed cmake-GUI, but when I want to use cmake instruction in terminal, the terminal told me that `cmake command not found`.

How can I get cmake instruction work in terminal? Should I use `brew install cmake` or use some configurations to make my cmake work in terminal?

Comment: yes 'brew  install  cmake' should work

Comment: I don't know your Mac. Did you set it up yourself? If not, you may want to search first, whether cmake is already present somewhere, and if is and the installed version suits you, I would use this instead.

Comment: How did you install cmake-GUI?  details....

Comment: Thanks guys, I used brew install cmake and made it ;)